# Bootstrap table sort not working on all columns

Tags: html, angular, mdbootstrap

I have a table that is created from an array in my .ts. I am using bootstrap to be able to sort the table when you click on the headers. This works for 2 columns but not the other 2. All of the data in the array is a string, and it all looks the same as each other.

**HTML**:

```
<table id="tableContents" mdbTable class="z-depth-1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index" aria-controls="tableContents" scope="col" [mdbTableSort]="filterData" [sortBy]="headElements[i]">{{head}} <mdb-icon fas icon="sort"></mdb-icon></th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let fact of filterData; let i = index"> 
    <td>{{ fact.Colour | titlecase }}</td>
    <td>{{ fact.Variant }}</td>
    <td>{{ fact.LastProcess }}</td>
    <td>{{ fact.LastProcessStatus }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  headElements = ['Colour', 'Variant', 'Process', 'Status'];

  filerData: any = [];

  filterData = [{
          Colour: "Red",
          Variant: "Left",
          LastProcess: "Run",
          LastProcessStatus: "Pass"
        },
        {
          Colour: "Black",
          Variant: "Right",
          LastProcess: "Walk",
          LastProcessStatus: "Fail"
        }
        ]

}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cpobd) of the problem. When you click on the headers it sorts the first two columns (`Colour` & `Variant`) but not the 3rd & 4th column.

Why is it doing this? And, how do I get it to sort all of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keys are not the same for the last 2 properties , it has to be the same

```
 headElements = ['Colour', 'Variant', 'Process', 'Status'];

 filerData: any = [];

 filterData = [{
      Colour: "Red",
      Variant: "Left",
      LastProcess: "Run", // **has to be Process**
      LastProcessStatus: "Pass" // **ha to be Status**
    },
    {
      Colour: "Black",
      Variant: "Right",
      LastProcess: "Walk",
      LastProcessStatus: "Fail"
    }
    ]
```

so your array has to be like this

```
filterData = [{
      Colour: "Red",
      Variant: "Left",
      Process: "Run",
      Status: "Pass" 
    },
    {
      Colour: "Black",
      Variant: "Right",
      Process: "Walk",
      Status: "Fail"
    }
]
```

and change them in your ngFor loop

```
<tr *ngFor="let fact of filterData; let i = index"> 
    <td>{{ fact.Colour | titlecase }}</td>
    <td>{{ fact.Variant }}</td>
    <td>{{ fact.Process }}</td>
    <td>{{ fact.Status }}</td>
</tr>
```